# using axway appcelerator Webview how can I download a file to the device

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

I am using Axway AppceleratorStudio sdk version 7.5.0.GA on Android and IOS.

I am rendering remote websites using the webview component.
The website has a file URL that when clicked should download the file (usually pdf or excel).

I am unable to download the file within the webview to the mobile device. The same link works on the mobile web browser.

On IOS the file gets downloaded and displayed within the webview itself which is not what i want. I would like the file to be downloaded to the device storage.

On Android clicking the download link does nothing even though I have the storage permissions enabled (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to intercept the click (eg. beforeLoad event) pause it and download the file with a normal HTTPClient inside Titanium.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The challenge i have is to detect the mime type in the beforeLoad event before it can be handled by the HTTPClient. I do not want have all links to be handled by the HTTPClient. Also the authentication cookie would need to be shared with the HTTPClient otherwise the user would get prompted for the userid/password for the remote site again.